# Enable hardware acceleration in WINE

Tags: wine, games, hardware-acceleration

I used WINE to install Bejeweled 3 from my game disk. When I start up, the resolution is set to a low 800x600.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKWNL.png

When I try to increase it I get the following message:

`3D acceleration must be enabled to switch to a higher resolution`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcFYl.png

This game runs great on my Windows 7 partition on a higher resolution, so I know I have whatever hardware is required to do so in Ubuntu. How can I enable 3D acceleration in WINE on Ubuntu 14.04?